# jshint grunt exported options

Tags: gruntjs, jshint

Hi I'm trying to achieve the following. I'm using grunt for jshint validating.

Somewhere in a file I have used:

```
var logger = function () {
 // some ode
}
```

Because logger is never actually used jshint correctly shows me the following error.

```
W098: 'logger' is defined but never used.
```

I could set unused to false and it would work perfectly. But I actually want the option to take place in other files and warn me about unused variables. So the unused option is not gonna work for me.

I also saw that I could use a inline comment like this:
* exported EXPORTED_LIB */

But I would actually prefer to avoid cluttering my files with such comments. Is there any chance I can specify an exported options in my grunt file like I can for example for globals.

Heres the jshint part of my gruntfile:

```
jshint: {
        // global options
        options: {
            camelcase: true,
            curly: true,
            eqeqeq: true,
            forin: true,
            immed: true,
            indent: 4,
            latedef: true,
            newcap: true,
            noarg: true,
            nonew: true,
            plusplus: false,
            quotmark: 'single',
            undef: true,
            unused: true,
            strict: true,
            maxparams: 4,
            maxdepth: 4,
            trailing: true,
            maxlen: 120,
            browser: true,
            node: true
        },
        server_logger: {
            src: [BASE_PATH_SERVER_LOGGER, '/**/*.js'].join(''),
            options: {
                browser: false
            }
        },
        client_logger: {
            src: [BASE_PATH_CLIENT_LOGGER, '/**/*.js'].join(''),
            options: {
                node: false,
                devel: true
            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Best regards
Playerwtf

**UPDATE:** I made an issue on jshint github repository [here](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was recently fixxed and works now as I would expect it.

[github-issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/commit/3c69009ce25760fdb7b5c2163d650291081847cb)

As an example I use it like this in my gruntfile

```
client_logger: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: BASE_PATH_CLIENT_LOGGER,
    src: '**/*.js',
    options: {
        node: false,
        devel: true,
        globals: {
            logger: true,
            expect: true,
            it: true,
            describe: true,
            beforeEach: true,
            afterEach: true
        },
        exported: ['logger']
    }
}
```

But the npm module was not yet updated. If you want this to work you will have to manually copy the newest version from the jshint github repository and replace the one in the current module or wait until it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can exclude files in your src-files, so you could exclude your logger file from your basic linting (i suppose the logger file is logger.js here), and lint the logger file separatly with the unused-flag turned off.

read more about that [here](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) -> *"! at the beginning of a pattern will negate the match"*

you could set the cwd (and leave the join stuff). see more about that in the docs: [Building the files object dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)

```
jshint: {
    // global options
    options: {
        ... your global options here
    },
    server_logger: {
        options: {
            browser: false
        },
        files: [{
          cwd: BASE_PATH_SERVER_LOGGER,
          src: ['/**/*.js', '!logger.js']
        }]
    },
    client_logger: {
        options: {
            node: false,
            devel: true
        },
        files: [{
          cwd: BASE_PATH_CLIENT_LOGGER,
          src: ['/**/*.js', '!logger.js']
        }]
    },
    lint_logger: {
        options: {
            unused: false
        },
        files: [{
          src: ['logger.js']
        }]
    }
}
```

not 100% sure if that works, but i think it should at least lead you into the right direction. if you need to specify a path and not only a file for excluding you could put your logger-file in a separate folder an just exclude that folder!

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I didn't new about cwd thanks for that.
Although I'm pretty sure your solution should work its not very elegant. I was considering the same as you mentioned but I think I will have more and more files such as logger.js and I don't like to specify all those separate. But I will have to see if there is an alternative.
I just really hoped for an option like exported: {// exported variables} as it works for globals